# What are good settings for Fortnite beginners?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Im just starting to play Fortnite and I want to know what settings I should use for sensitivity, building, etc. YOU DO NOT, have to give me a full essay on your Fortnite settings. Just give me good settings I should use as a beginner. I am on Xbox by the way.

Comment: This will attract many opinions instead of fact-based answers. Our site does not allow opinion based questions.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so the best sensitivity for all (except building and editing) is roughly 0.5,  more or less depending on your preferences.
Make sure quick-build is on because you will be training yourself wrong by not using it.

Have fun!